# VBA checking the value of a cell for XLErrValue #VALUE! throwing type mismatch

Tags: vba, excel

Why does the follow code throw a **`Type mismatch`** error

```
If Range("J" & i).Value = CVErr(xlErrValue) Then
    Range("J" & i).Interior.Color = 255
End If
```

Should I be using something other than `.Value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function `CVErr()` returns a value of `Error` type. You cannot compare this value with any other type of data than `Error`, since it causes **Run-time 13: Type mismatch** error.

In order to avoid this error you need to modify your code like below:

```
If VBA.IsError(Range("J" & i).Value) Then
    If Range("J" & i).Value = CVErr(xlErrValue) Then
        Range("J" & i).Interior.Color = 255
    End If
End If
```